# To make background transparent in Android

Tags: android

Hello I want to make my app's background transparent as camera preview.
I searched following code online:

```
SurfaceView sfvTrack = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.sfvTrack);  
sfvTrack.setZOrderOnTop(true);  
SurfaceHolder sfhTrackHolder = sfvTrack.getHolder();
sfhTrackHolder.setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSPARENT);
```

But I got stuck at finding R.id.sfvTrack.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Replace it by the id you used for your surface view.  If you aren't using a surface view, this probably isn't the code you should be using.

Answer (score 0):

As @Gabe said in the comments, `R.id.sfvTrack` is searching for a `SurfaceView` with an id of "sfvTrack" you can create one in your layout file that you made, but this isn't the best way to make a transparent background.